# jQuery UI Modal Dialog - Prevent Action Unless OK clicked

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

**EDIT**:

I want to replace the following with a jquery UI dialog:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="foo" runat="server" OnClick="someMethodThatPostsBack" OnClientClick="return confirmAction()" Text="Delete" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function confirmAction() {
        return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this?");
    }
</script>
```

I don't want the action to post back unless the OK is clicked on the dialog. It works perfectly fine in regular javascript with confirm. I would like to replace it with jQuery UI dialog so it looks a little prettier. Is it possible?

I created a dialog that I open when I click a link or a button:

```
<a id="aboutLink" href="/Home/About">About</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#aboutLInk").click(function() { 
        $("myDialog").dialog({
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "OK": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                },
                Cancel: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
        }
        });
    });
</script>
```

When I click the link it takes me to the About page. I want to be able to show the dialog and only go to the About page depending on if they click the OK button on the dialog. If they hit cancel, it should not do anything. How can I accomplish this?

Also, if I create the dialog every time I click the button do I need to destroy the dialog as well somehow? How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can't really do this - the `click` handler returns immediately so you have to prevent the link from being followed yourself, if (and only if) Javascript is enabled.

   (Return `false` from your cancel handler to prevent the link from being followed)

   To actually change page address when clicking `OK`, set `window.location` in the callback.
2. Yes, you do need to destroy the dialog when it's finished with - replacing `close` with `destroy` in your event handlers should achieve that.

I put a working demo at http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/WWVEg/

```
$("#aboutLink").click(function() {
    var that = this;         // save a reference to the clicked link
    $("#myDialog").dialog({
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "OK": function() {
                $(this).dialog("destroy");
                window.location = that.href;
            },
            Cancel: function() {
                $(this).dialog("destroy");
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

FWIW, it's probably not strictly necessary to close or destroy the dialog in the OK callback seeing as the next line is going to cause a page reload anyway - I expect the new page load would be faster without it.

Comment: Is there a way to do this that is more generic? This only works if I'm doing it as part of a regular link. What if I wanted to do it for a button press that will execute some javascript unless I hit cancel. Or if the link contains some javascript to do a post?

Comment: Specifically, I want to be able to do this in an ASP.net application. I have a LinkButton that will make a postback to delete a record. Before I would do a regular javascript popup and return false/true but I would like to make it a little more pretty and use a jquery dialog in its place...but the jquery dialog isn't blocking.

Comment: no, jQuery dialog doesn't block the way `alert()` does.  Technically you could put your browser into a "busy loop" while you're waiting for the click but after a while the browser would complain that the script is taking too long to execute.

Comment: You might want to pass in `event` to the click function and use `event.preventDefault();` instead of `return false;`, as the latter will stop propagation, and you might not want that if you have other events that need to bubble up. Still +1 though =D

Comment: you could also fake the busy loop with a short period `setInterval()` call, which would at least avoid the latter problem.

Answer (score 0):

Oh boy, this is old... but I ran in to the same problem as you and decided to do it like this:

```
jQuery(function () {
    var accepted = false;
    jQuery('#dialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        bgiframe: true,
        width: 450,
        modal: true,
        open: function () {
            accepted = false;
        },
        buttons: {
            "Accept": function () {
                accepted = true;
                jQuery(this).dialog("close");
            },
            Cancel: function () {
                jQuery(this).dialog("close");
            }
        },
        close: function () {
            if (accepted == false) {
                jQuery("#chkBox").prop("checked", false);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Basically I just declared a boolean variable that changes when "OK" or "Accept" is clicked. The close function checks that boolean value, and if it's set to false, it unchecks my checkbox. If it's set to true, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do same thing using jQuery UI dialog.

Your ASPX button code:

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Width="100px">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClientClick="javascript:return deleteItem(this.name, this.alt);"
                                    CommandArgument='<%# Eval("id") %>' CommandName='<%# Eval("status") %>' Text='<%# Eval("status").ToString().Trim().Equals("y") ? "Deactive"  : "Active"   %>' />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
```

Javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        InitializeDeleteConfirmation();
    });

    function InitializeDeleteConfirmation() {
        $('#dialog-confirm').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            resizable: false,
            height: 140,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Delete": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                },
                Cancel: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
    }
    function confirmDelete() {
        return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this?");

    }
    function deleteItem(uniqueID) {    

    $("#dialog-confirm").html("Are you sure you want to change the status ?");

    $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
        title: 'Confirm',
        height: 150,
        width: 400,
        buttons: {
            "Yes": function () { __doPostBack(uniqueID, ''); 
                      $(this).dialog("close"); },
            "No": function () { $(this).dialog("close"); }
        }
    });

    $('#dialog-confirm').dialog('open');
    return false;
} 


</script>
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

After seeing the comments, below is what works smoothly

**Doing it in jQuery UI**

You can use plugin [jquery.confirm](https://myclabs.github.io/jquery.confirm/) and then add `$("#btndelete").trigger("click.confirmed");` in the confirmation events

### Usage:

**Requirements**

- jQuery > 1.8
- jquery.confirm plugin
- Bootstrap

  ```
  $("#btndelete").confirm({
     title:"Delete confirmation",
     text:"Are you sure you want to delete ???",
     confirm: function(button) {
        // Do something..
        $("#btndelete").trigger("click.confirmed");// it is to trigger
          //the same elements click event which we would trigger without a
          //confirmation dialog
        //alert("You just confirmed.");
     },
     cancel: function(button) {
        // Do something
        //alert("You aborted the operation.");
     },
    confirmButton: "Yes I am sure",
    cancelButton: "No Do not Delete"  });
  ```

Of course, the solution for those who face the issue ***now onwards***